# Erro ao adicionar FOREIGN KEY em tabela já criada

Tags: mysql, sql, chave-estrangeira

Tenho uma tabela que preciso ser altera para ter uma chave estrangeira

> ALTER TABLE bancocliente.produto ADD CONSTRAINT fk_fabPro FOREIGN KEY
>   (cod_fab) REFERENCES bancocliente.fabrica (code);

Recebo a mensagem de erro:

```
Erro SQL (1452): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bancocliente`.`#sql-2eb8_2`, CONSTRAINT `fk_fabPro` FOREIGN KEY (`cod_fab`) REFERENCES `fabrica` (`code`))
```

Codigo da criação da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `produto` (
    `code` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cod_fab` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `nome` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `preco` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;
```

e tabela fabrica

```
CREATE TABLE `fabrica` (
    `code` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nome` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6
;
```

Imagem do erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80515/discussion-on-question-by-alexjosesilva-erro-ao-adicionar-foreign-key-em-tabela)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução desenvolvida juntamente com a ajuda de @RovannLinhalis

Fazer um backup das tabelas a serem alteras
**produto
fabrica**

para

**produto_bk
fabrica_bk**

Apagar os dados das tabelas

**produto
fabrica**

executar o comando sql: 
ALTER TABLE bancocliente.produto ADD CONSTRAINT fk_fabPro FOREIGN KEY (cod_fab) REFERENCES bancocliente.fabrica (code);

Apos estes passo, populei novamente as tabelas de forma correta.